# Ionic to BT Thermal image and font adjustment using esc-pos-encoder-ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, printing, escpos

Looking forward to someone who could correct or guide me thru this,
I've been doing a simple Ionic Mobile App,
Using the references [Here](https://openbase.com/js/esc-pos-encoder-ionic/documentation),
so far I'm able to do basic printing of text and formats, however whenever I tried printing images it doesn't print, and adjusting the font height and width using dynamic dimensions with printer esc/pos commands, it just prints on the default font.

Here's my code

```
import { Component, ViewChild, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import EscPosEncoder from 'esc-pos-encoder-ionic';
import { commands } from '../printer/printer-command';
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/bluetooth-serial/ngx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {
  testFont() {
      let img = new Image()
      img.src = 'assets/header.bmp'

      const encoder = new EscPosEncoder();
      const result = encoder.initialize();
      result
      .image(img, 300, 300, 'atkinson', 128)
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_4SQUARE)
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_FONT_A)
      .line('4SQUARE FONT A')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_4SQUARE)
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_FONT_B)
      .line('4SQUARE FONT B')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_4SQUARE)
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_FONT_C)
      .line('4SQUARE FONT C')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_NORMAL)
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_FONT_A)
      .line('NORMAL FONT A')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_NORMAL)
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_FONT_B)
      .line('NORMAL FONT B')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_NORMAL)
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_FONT_C)
      .line('NORMAL FONT C')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_CUSTOM_SIZE(33,25))
      .line('CUSTOM SIZE TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_CUSTOM_SIZE(21,18))
      .line('CUSTOM SIZE TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_CUSTOM_SIZE(11,18))
      .line('CUSTOM SIZE TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_HEIGHT[1])
      .line('HEIGHT TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_HEIGHT[2])
      .line('HEIGHT TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_HEIGHT[3])
      .line('HEIGHT TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_HEIGHT[4])
      .line('HEIGHT TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_HEIGHT[5])
      .line('HEIGHT TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_WIDTH[1])
      .line('WIDTH TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_WIDTH[2])
      .line('WIDTH TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_WIDTH[3])
      .line('WIDTH TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_WIDTH[4])
      .line('WIDTH TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_WIDTH[5])
      .line('WIDTH TEST')
      .raw(commands.TEXT_FORMAT.TXT_2WIDTH)
      .line('2WIDTH TEST')
      .size('small')
      .line('small text')
      .size('normal')
      .line('A line of normal text')
      const resultByte = result.encode();

      this.bluetoothSerial.connect(this.MAC).subscribe(() => {
       this.bluetoothSerial.write(resultByte)
       .then(() => {
         this.printNotif()
         this.bluetoothSerial.disconnect();
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         this.printError(err)
         this.bluetoothSerial.disconnect();
       });
  
      })

    }
}
```

Here's my printer commands for esc/pos

```
//commands based on https://github.com/humbertopiaia/escpos-commands-js/blob/master/src/commands.js
//all the commands below may vary by printer, check the manual
export const commands = {
    LF: [0x0a],
    ESC: [0x1b],
    FS: [0x1c],
    GS: [0x1d],
    US: [0x1f],
    FF: [0x0c],
    DLE: [0x10],
    DC1: [0x11],
    DC4: [0x14],
    EOT: [0x04],
    NUL: [0x00],
    //EOL: [\n],
    HORIZONTAL_LINE: {
      HR_58MM: '================================',
      HR2_58MM: '********************************'
    },
    FEED_CONTROL_SEQUENCES: {
      CTL_LF: [0x0a], // Print and line feed
      CTL_FF: [0x0c], // Form feed
      CTL_CR: [0x0d], // Carriage return
      CTL_HT: [0x09], // Horizontal tab
      CTL_VT: [0x0b], // Vertical tab
    },
    LINE_SPACING: {
      LS_DEFAULT: [0x1b,0x32],
      LS_SET: [0x1b,0x33]
    },
    HARDWARE: {
      HW_INIT: [0x1b,0x40], // Clear data in buffer and reset modes
      HW_SELECT: [0x1b,0x3d,0x01], // Printer select
      HW_RESET: [0x1b,0x3f,0x0a,0x00], // Reset printer hardware
    },
    CASH_DRAWER: {
      CD_KICK_2: [0x1b,0x70,0x00], // Sends a pulse to pin 2 []
      CD_KICK_5: [0x1b,0x70,0x01], // Sends a pulse to pin 5 []
    },
    MARGINS: {
      BOTTOM: [0x1b,0x4f], // Fi0x bottom size
      LEFT: [0x1b,0x6c], // Fi0x left size
      RIGHT: [0x1b,0x51], // Fi0x right size
    },
    PAPER: {
      PAPER_FULL_CUT: [0x1d,0x56,0x00], // Full cut paper
      PAPER_PART_CUT: [0x1d,0x56,0x01], // Partial cut paper
      PAPER_CUT_A: [0x1d,0x56,0x41], // Partial cut paper
      PAPER_CUT_B: [0x1d,0x56,0x42], // Partial cut paper
    },
    TEXT_FORMAT: {
      TXT_NORMAL: [0x1b,0x21,0x00], // Normal text
      TXT_2HEIGHT: [0x1b,0x21,0x10], // Double height text
      TXT_2WIDTH: [0x1b,0x21,0x20], // Double width text
      TXT_4SQUARE: [0x1b,0x21,0x30], // Double width & height text
      TXT_CUSTOM_SIZE: function (width, height) { // other sizes
        var widthDec = (width - 1) * 16;
        var heightDec = height - 1;
        var sizeDec = widthDec + heightDec;
        return [0x1d,0x21,String.fromCharCode(sizeDec)]
      },
  
      TXT_HEIGHT: {
        1: [0x00],
        2: [0x01],
        3: [0x02],
        4: [0x03],
        5: [0x04],
        6: [0x05],
        7: [0x06],
        8: [0x07]
      },
      TXT_WIDTH: {
        1: [0x00],
        2: [0x10],
        3: [0x20],
        4: [0x30],
        5: [0x40],
        6: [0x50],
        7: [0x60],
        8: [0x70]
      },
  
      TXT_UNDERL_OFF: [0x1b,0x2d,0x00], // Underline font OFF
      TXT_UNDERL_ON: [0x1b,0x2d,0x01], // Underline font 1-dot ON
      TXT_UNDERL2_ON: [0x1b,0x2d,0x02], // Underline font 2-dot ON
      TXT_BOLD_OFF: [0x1b,0x45,0x00], // Bold font OFF
      TXT_BOLD_ON: [0x1b,0x45,0x01], // Bold font ON
      TXT_ITALIC_OFF: [0x1b,0x35], // Italic font ON
      TXT_ITALIC_ON: [0x1b,0x34], // Italic font ON
      TXT_FONT_A: [0x1b,0x4d,0x00], // Font type A
      TXT_FONT_B: [0x1b,0x4d,0x01], // Font type B
      TXT_FONT_C: [0x1b,0x4d,0x02], // Font type C
      TXT_ALIGN_LT: [0x1b,0x61,0x00], // Left justification
      TXT_ALIGN_CT: [0x1b,0x61,0x01], // Centering
      TXT_ALIGN_RT: [0x1b,0x61,0x02], // Right justification
    },
    BARCODE_FORMAT: {
      BARCODE_TXT_OFF: '\x1d\x48\x00', // HRI barcode chars OFF
      BARCODE_TXT_ABV: '\x1d\x48\x01', // HRI barcode chars above
      BARCODE_TXT_BLW: '\x1d\x48\x02', // HRI barcode chars below
      BARCODE_TXT_BTH: '\x1d\x48\x03', // HRI barcode chars both above and below

      BARCODE_FONT_A: '\x1d\x66\x00', // Font type A for HRI barcode chars
      BARCODE_FONT_B: '\x1d\x66\x01', // Font type B for HRI barcode chars

      BARCODE_HEIGHT: function(height) { // Barcode Height [1-255]
          return '\x1d\x68' + String.fromCharCode(height);
      },
      // Barcode Width  [2-6]
      BARCODE_WIDTH: {
          1: '\x1d\x77\x02',
          2: '\x1d\x77\x03',
          3: '\x1d\x77\x04',
          4: '\x1d\x77\x05',
          5: '\x1d\x77\x06',
      },
      BARCODE_HEIGHT_DEFAULT: '\x1d\x68\x64', // Barcode height default:100
      BARCODE_WIDTH_DEFAULT: '\x1d\x77\x01', // Barcode width default:1

      BARCODE_UPC_A: '\x1d\x6b\x00', // Barcode type UPC-A
      BARCODE_UPC_E: '\x1d\x6b\x01', // Barcode type UPC-E
      BARCODE_EAN13: '\x1d\x6b\x02', // Barcode type EAN13
      BARCODE_EAN8: '\x1d\x6b\x03', // Barcode type EAN8
      BARCODE_CODE39: '\x1d\x6b\x04', // Barcode type CODE39
      BARCODE_ITF: '\x1d\x6b\x05', // Barcode type ITF
      BARCODE_NW7: '\x1d\x6b\x06', // Barcode type NW7
      BARCODE_CODE93: '\x1d\x6b\x48', // Barcode type CODE93
      BARCODE_CODE128: '\x1d\x6b\x49', // Barcode type CODE128
  },
  }
```

and here's the result which it all becomes on default, I tried it on a different BT printer it prints out the same, so I guess the model isn't the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use de image.onload method to load and resolve your resultByte like this:

```
  let img = new Image();
  let resultByte = null;
  img.src = 'assets/header.bmp'
  const result = encoder.initialize();
  img.onload = () => {
    result 
      .image(img, 300, 300, 'atkinson', 128)
      // rest of your encode proccess
    resultByte = result.encode();
    // Rest of printing process (Bluetooth Serial in your case)
  }
```

This will wait for image load as the documentation indicates
[EscPosEncoder](https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/EscPosEncoder#image)